Pattern match using awk
I have an input file as below
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4
abc123|654565|abc|apple
abc123|654565|pir|orange
abc123|654565|val|plum

I want to select all the lines that have Col2=654565 and Col3=abc and print the Col4 value of the resulting line.
How would I do this using awk?

Like this: awk -F\| '$2 == "654565" && $3 == "abc" { print $4 }'
The -F argument tells awk to use | as the field separator instead of whitespace, and \ is to escape the | since it'd otherwise be special to the shell.
From there, it's a straightforward translation of your requirements into awk.

Unlikely to be a concern here, but note that the quotes around 654565 mean it will be a string lexical comparison instead of a number comparison. For instance, $2 == "544565" will return false for values of $2 such as 654565.00 or 6.54565e+5 or +654565 or if there is whitespace around 654565. Without the quotes, it would be a number comparison if $2 looks like a number (ignoring whitespace at the start and end), and string comparison otherwise.

Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica has already given a working solution using awk, but since the data appears to be a set of CSV records, I thought I'd mention a couple of solutions using Miller (mlr), too (a CSV-aware utility for parsing CSV and other structured formats).
First, a straight translation of the awk code.  Since Miller is CSV-aware, it allows us to address the fields by name, which means we are no longer dependent on the ordering of the fields in the file.
mlr --csv --fs pipe put -q '$Col2 == 654565 && $Col3 == "abc" { print $Col4 }' file

This reads the pipe-delimited CSV data and outputs the Col4 value for any record that fulfils the criteria.  The -q option to the put verb turns off the automatic output of each record (a bit like -n with sed).
Another approach with Miller is first to filter all records and then use cut to extract the wanted field:
mlr --csv --fs pipe --headerless-csv-output \
    filter '$Col2 == 654565 && $Col3 == "abc"' then \
    cut -f Col4 file

This produces a CSV data set with headers, so we use --headerless-csv-output to turn the headers off (can be shortened to just --ho).

Using csvsql:
$ csvsql -d'|' --query 'SELECT Col4 FROM file WHERE Col2 = 654565 AND Col3 = "abc"' file | tail -n +2


Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
Return header and full matching rows:
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'get.put;  \
                        my @a = csv(in => $*IN, sep => "|");  \
                        @a.=map( {$_ if .[1] == 654565 && .[2] eq "abc" });  \
                        csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT, sep => "|");'   file

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku features rational math as well as high-level support for Unicode, built-in. Here Raku's Text::CSV module is used to provide an authentic CSV parser.

In the first statement, we get the header line and output it (use get.put xx 2 for a 2-line header, etc.). To skip the header, just use get alone.
In the second statement, the Text::CSV module's high-level csv() function is used. Input is taken off $*IN Stdin, and the separator is altered to suit the input. Data is saved to the @a array.
In the third statement, map() is used to filter each CSV row. The .= meta-operator applies the map as a filter to the input array, essentially a shortened version of @a = @a.map(...). Like Perl, Raku has Type-specific equality operators: == tests for numeric equality while eq tests for string-equality.
Finally, the filtered @a array is returned on $*OUT Stdout.

Sample Input:
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4
abc123|654565|abc|apple
abc123|654565|pir|orange
abc123|654565|val|plum

Sample Output (full matching rows):
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4
abc123|654565|abc|apple


SO HOW TO RETURN ONLY THE FOURTH COLUMN?
Just swap the last Raku statement out for the following (will return apple):
.put for @a.map: *.[3];

#OR:

.put for @a>>.[3];

https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.md
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org
